# \nopagebreak in longtable results in undesired negative vertical space

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, longtable

System: XeTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX).

MWE (with a grid superimposed to help visualizing the issue):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=72pt,left=72pt,bottom=72pt,right=72pt,width=396pt,height=612pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[step=18pt]{pagegrid}
\pagegridsetup{top-left}
\usepackage{longtable,ltabptch}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{12}{18}\selectfont
\vspace*{6.5pt}
% No space deleted with \nopagebreak on next line
\lipsum[2] \nopagebreak
\lipsum[2]
\begin{longtable}{ll} C11 & C12\\ C21 & C22 \end{longtable}
\lipsum[2]
% Use of \nopagebreak in the longtable deletes some vertical space and line spacing is disturbed
\begin{longtable}{ll} C11 & C12\\ \nopagebreak C21 & C22 \\ \nopagebreak \end{longtable}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You know that TeX uses stretchy space, right, which it uses to help ensure good vertical spacing and avoid bad breaks? This means that the more you constrain where it can break things, the more it will try to compensate by adjusting what stretchy space it has to work with. This includes the space around section breaks, tables, lists etc. etc. I don't know if that's the issue here but it might not be that the space is deleted. It might be shrunk (negative stretchiness) in the second case or stretched (positive stretchiness) in the first. Most stretchy space has both negative and positive bits.

Comment: Can't be the problem here, though. The disparity is caused by `ltabptch` since the vertical space is not there in either case by default.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a dirty hack, but works. By trial and error, I found that the problem arises only if `\nopagebreak` is used in the first row of a longtable. So I created a blank first row without a `\nopagebreak`, and then added negative vertical space equal to `\baselineskip`. The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=72pt,left=72pt,bottom=72pt,right=72pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[step=18pt]{pagegrid}
\pagegridsetup{top-left}
\usepackage{longtable,ltabptch}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{12}{18}\selectfont
\vspace*{6.5pt}
% No space deleted with \nopagebreak on next line
\lipsum[2] \nopagebreak
\lipsum[2]
\begin{longtable}{ll}
C11 & C12\\
C21 & C22
\end{longtable}
\lipsum[2]
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\baselineskip}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
% Add a dummy first line and then add negative vertical space equal to \baselineskip
 & \\ [-\the\mylen]
C11 & C12\\ \nopagebreak
C21 & C22 \\ \nopagebreak
\end{longtable}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image: longtable-fixed]